# Is it worth using non-VOC or low-VOC interior paint?

Tags: painting, remodeling

I’m remodeling a condo and painting the walls and ceiling. For context, I've heard that Valspar paint has no VOCs and may be preferable to Sherwin-Williams for health reasons. However, my general contractor wants to use Sherwin-Williams paint (with VOCs) because he “has an account” with them.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic if you reword to VOC / non VOC it would be ok.

Comment: I see the edited question is going through the reopen process. Good.

Comment: Also consider that your state may limit the total VOC content. It may be illegal to use a paint from out-of-state with higher VOCs, even if the contractor can get them directly from a distributor.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an FYI, if you're going to heavily color the paint, be aware that a lot of tints are **not** low-VOC. From [this site](https://www.todayshomeowner.com/video/tinting-colorant-can-add-vocs-to-paint/)

> Low or no Voc (Volatile Organic Compound) house paints are great, since they have little odor and limit harmful chemicals in the air. But tinting the paint often defeat the purpose by adding unwanted VOCs back into the paint.
>
> To make sure the air in your home is VOC-free, use factory tinted no VOC paint, or paints that use a VOC-free colorant

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the low/no VOC paints. In particular, I can tell you that Sherwin-Williams paints sure are smelly. Real nice, but smelly. Honestly I'm coming to really appreciate Home Depot's Behr paints. Much less smelly and just as nice as the Sherwin-Williams stuff IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The VOC levels in paints do matter. Not only when paint is applied and drying, but also as the coating breaks down over time. VOCs interact with other airborne particulates and can pose serious health risks over time.

I used Sherwin-Williams ProMar 200 paint line extensively for my projects and my customers were always satisfied with results. SW also offers a product called Harmony. I tried that a long time ago when it was first released and was not happy with it at all. Maybe it has been improved since that time. Those are the two options for ZERO VOC at SW.

BTW, Sherwin Williams purchased Valspar about a year ago. I wouldn't be surprised if Valspar paint is already repackaged SW paint.

Answer (score 0):

I work in the paint department at Lowe's and all of the Valspar paint that we carry, as well as the colorant that we use to tint the paint, is ZERO-VOC. In truth, most of your higher quality paints are LOW- or ZERO-VOC and are much more safe then they had been in the past.